Geth: can't run eth.Ethereum in light sync mode, light mode has been deprecated
I have just downloaded freshly new version of Geth on Ubuntu and get this error:
Fatal: Failed to register the Ethereum service: can't run eth.Ethereum in light sync mode, light mode has been deprecated
How that's possible? This article https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/nodes-and-clients/light-clients/ has last edit 5 March 2024.
Command:
$ geth --syncmode light

Full error:
INFO [05-16|19:56:12.106] Starting Geth on Ethereum mainnet...
INFO [05-16|19:56:12.106] Bumping default cache on mainnet         provided=1024 updated=4096
INFO [05-16|19:56:12.108] Maximum peer count                       ETH=50 total=50
INFO [05-16|19:56:12.111] Smartcard socket not found, disabling    err="stat /run/pcscd/pcscd.comm: no such file or directory"
INFO [05-16|19:56:12.115] Set global gas cap                       cap=50,000,000
INFO [05-16|19:56:12.129] Initializing the KZG library             backend=gokzg
Fatal: Failed to register the Ethereum service: can't run eth.Ethereum in light sync mode, light mode has been deprecated


I found answer: Light nodes are not currently working on proof-of-stake Ethereum.
https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/fundamentals/sync-modes
